# Parse multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

main goal: the whole array should be converted to XML later.

I want to do following things:
 For every key (e.g. 12772) data has to be fetched from a database so I can not convert it simply. The fetched data will be attributes of a tag.

My idea was to combine the deepest childs to one xml string. But how can I detect if I am in the deepest level? I have thought kind of a do...while-loop but I don't know how to check exactly if the element has a child or not.

The array depth can vary as you can see:

```
Array
(
    [12772]=>Array
        (
            [16563]=>Array
                (
                    [0] => <xml>Information 1</xml>
                    [1] => <xml>Information 2</xml>
                )
        )

    [16532]=>Array
        (
            [0] => <xml>Information 1</xml>
            [1] => <xml>Information 2</xml>
        )

)
```

Any help is very appreciated!

/edit:
Output should be:

```
<xml>
<testsuite id='12772' name='fetched from database'>
   <testsuite id='16563' name='fetched from database'>
      <testcase id='0'>Information 1</testcase>
      <testcase id='1'>Information 2</testcase>
   </testsuite>
</testsuite>
<testsuite id='16532' name='fetched from database'>
   <testcase id='0'>Information 1</testcase>
   <testcase id='1'>Information 2</testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive is the best to loop into tree like structure. Basically, a recursive function is a function that call itself. By example:

```
$input = Array
(
    12772=>Array
        (
            16563=>Array
                (
                    0 => '<xml>Information 1</xml>',
                    1 => '<xml>Information 2</xml>'
                )
        ),
    16532=>Array
        (
            0 => '<xml>Information 1</xml>',
            1 => '<xml>Information 2</xml>'
        )

);

$xml = "";

recursiveFunction($xml, $input);

var_dump($xml);

function recursiveFunction(&$output, $node, $id = 0, $level = 0)
{

    if (is_array($node)) {

        if ($level === 0) {

             $output .= "<xml>" . PHP_EOL;

         } else {

            $output .= str_repeat("\t", $level) . "<testsuite id='" .  $id . " name='fetched from database'>" . PHP_EOL;
        } 

        foreach ($node as $id => $newNode) {
            recursiveFunction($output, $newNode, $id, $level + 1);
        }

        if ($level === 0) {

             $output .= "</xml>";

         } else {

            $output .= str_repeat("\t", $level) . "</testsuite>" . PHP_EOL;
        } 

    } else {

        $output .= str_repeat("\t", $level) . "<testcase id='" .  $id . "'>" . $node . "</testcase>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

You can test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcabd9ffccc1a05621d8a21ef4b14f29b4a765ca

Comment: thanks for your input. but how do I know in which level/path I am? I want to "merge" the $nodes that are not an array together, but the merged value should stay in the same level. Like deleting the old values and set one new. My example XML is maybe not the best, the "Information 1" should be a seperate tag, I want those tags in one array value.

Comment: I updated my code so you can have the level and the path. Now, I'm not so sure I understand you want to output things, is it an array or xml? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a047ef69786391d8ece1cfbad9a24a8c72f2a428

Comment: The output later should be XML, I have added the format to the main question!

Comment: Do you expect me to do the XML part too or do you want to give a try. I'll be working today, so don't expect me to help you in the next 10 hours.

Comment: I try to do it by myself! I'll post the solution here or if I have problems I'll ask again. Thank you!!

Comment: I have issues with my scope.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74a7bc70f95d3b99405eef6b5a11fe8c73e4f1d1
I try to stuff all results into an array. But I think it is not accessible in the recursive function. I have seen a pass-by with an '&' infront of the array, but they always used it when calling the function again. 

There is another problem: The parent ID's (arrays/testsuites) are only allowed once in the xml. So I am asking myself how to combine them together (Example as comment in the sandbox). It would be nice if you could help me again!

Comment: You are lucky, my testing of send large files of FTP connection is quite long and I have a few time to spare for you (I will also updat my answer). http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb3b42da0e5886c5a2041fb9e428911a2f5bf0fb

Comment: As I can see it the solution should work! Thank you very much! I have to think about the recursive function tomorrow as I am going to sleep soon. I'll try to implement it tomorrow too.
There is one </testsuite> tag too much but it occurs every time so I can strip it off (altrough it may be a bit dirty).

May the bandwith be with you!

Comment: Oh, you're right, I fixed that http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dcabd9ffccc1a05621d8a21ef4b14f29b4a765ca. Good succes.